# Recyclerview Dividers won't show up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, divider

### Dividers

I have a `RecyclerView' to which I'm trying to add dividers.

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(
mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL));
```

but when I load the app I get no dividers.
What am I missing?

### Code

This is the whole Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private String[] myDataset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        myDataset = new String[]{"Cool", "Dope", "Awesome"};

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL));



        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset, "Item");
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

#### Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] mDataset;
private String mCategory;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemCategory;
    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        itemCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemCategory);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(String[] dataset, String category) {
    mDataset = dataset;
    mCategory = category;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.sweep_text_view_layout, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.itemName.setText(mDataset[position]);
    holder.itemCategory.setText(mCategory);

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
}`
```

Comment: What is the background color of the activity xml layout containing the recyclerviews

Comment: There's no background-color. I also tried to set it as blue and orange, but nothing seems to appear @Eenvincible

Comment: Why are you using `getContext()` instead of `MainActivity.this`?

Comment: Saw it on an answer @cricket_007 . However even with MainActivity.this it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, then. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/a-view-divided-adding-dividers-to-your-recyclerview-with-itemdecoration/

Comment: Can you share the code for decoration?

Comment: Mmmmm consider I have no class DividerItemDecoration, I just imported it with import `android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;` @cricket_007

Comment: I thought there was a default decoration...

Comment: Oh, so they now have one that comes with the support library; I have been using custom

Comment: I don't know, but according to that article I linked in my question, I just need to do this, but it doesn't seem to work @Eenvincible

Comment: You didn't set the orientation of the layout  manager

Comment: I now set it on the XML, or should I do something more? @cricket_007

Comment: You can't set a layout manager orientation in xml, that's a LinearLayout, which is different

Comment: Oh, I get it, so how do I set a LayoutManager orientation? @cricket_007

Comment: You could check the documentation for the layout manager class, but the default orientation is vertical... Do you really need a Recyclerview here, anyway? It's such a simple list that it doesn't provide any benefit over listview

Comment: The problem could be your adapter class, but you've not shown that code

Comment: Yes I do, this is just the beginning of my App. The whole concept is a list which needs to update itself very often and I need something like a RecyclerView to do this smoother @cricket_007

Comment: Uploaded the adapter's code @cricket_007 anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom code:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("ALL")
 public class DividerItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration 
 {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

private static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

private final Drawable mDivider;

private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecorator(Context context, 
@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue") int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

private void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

private void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

private void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, int itemPosition, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Then apply the decoration like this:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecorator(this, 
    DividerItemDecorator.VERTICAL_LIST));
```